# Unused imports - any disadvantages?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I guess anyone who developed any Java- or Android-Programs with Eclipse has faced the unused imports warning at leat once.

Although I always remove those unused imports before releasing my program/app I'd like to know if there is any real disadvantage when not removing the unused imports.

Basically an import-statement just saves the programmer some typing and maintains readability of the code.
The only downsite I can see is that you might 'pollute' your programs namespace with many unused static members.

Any other downsides I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

maybe more probable naming conflicts too :D